# Why is my bootstrap affix navbar inside my carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this site, I have this navbar:
[picture of the site before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTDb4.png)

Then, I decided to use the affix bootstrap thing in the navbar, so the user would be able to access it's functions while scrolling down the page. But then, that happened: [picture with the affix pluggin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYxbg.png)

Keeping it simple, the navbar was swallowed by the carousel when I added `data-spy="affix"` to the tag `<nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">`. Its important to notice that, once in this position, its fixed in the window as you scroll the page, but not the way it should. And as I can't post any more link, nor can I embed Images, because I'm a noob, I'll just say that it keeps the same position relative to the browser window and the carousel controls stopped working.

This is the html code in body:

```
<body bgcolor="#f9ffe5">
<div id="main-div" class="container"> 
    <div class="title"> <!--------------------title-------------------->
        <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo-big.png" class="img img-responsive logo" /></div>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-Fale-Conosco">Fale Conosco!</button>
    </div>

    <nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix"><!-------navbar------->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">
                <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"> 
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button type="submit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
                            </button>
                        </span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#titleNavbar"> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="titleNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Empresa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Produtos <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trabalhe Conosco</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="home-page-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><!-------carousel------>
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active"> 
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/carousel/0.jpg" alt="Produtos reforçados em cores variadas e design moderno!"> 
            </div>
            <div class="item"> 
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/carousel/1.jpg" alt="Fabricamos produtos descartaveis! Atendemos e entregamos em todo o Brasil!"> 
            </div>
            <div class="item"> 
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/carousel/2.jpg" alt="Consulte disponibilidade de produtos para pronta entrega! Pagamento facilitado!"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#homePageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span> </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#homePageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span> </a>
    </div>

    <div class="row centered-row catalog"> <!------catalog(prototype)------->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 catalog-item">
            <img src="img/products/taca_45_vrm.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive img-catalog" alt="Taça 45ml">
            <h3>Taça 45 ml</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 catalog-item">
            <img src="img/products/copo_45_azc.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive img-catalog" alt="Copo 45ml">
            <h3>Copo 45 ml</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 catalog-item">
            <img src="img/products/garfo_ref_prt.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive img-catalog" alt="Garfo Refeição Reforçado">
            <h3>Garfo Refeição Reforçado</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, the ccs for the custom bootstrap navbar:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #1ba30b;
  border-color: #006310;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: green;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #1ba30b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #006310;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider {
  background-color: #006310;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #006310;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #006310;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #006310;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #006310;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #006310;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #006310;
  }
}
```

And the css for the custom bootstrap carousel

```
.carousel .carousel-indicators li{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: forestgreen;
}

.carousel .carousel-indicators li.active{
    background-color: forestgreen;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.centered-row{
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1+, Android 1.5+ */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4 */
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-triangle-right,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-triangle-left {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-left,
.glyphicon-chevron-right {
    color:forestgreen;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Finally the css for the custom search input:

```
.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon{
    background: white !important; 
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control{
    border-right:0; 
    box-shadow:0 0 0; 
    border-color:#ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button{
    border:0;
    background:transparent;
}

div.stylish-input-group{
    max-width: 187px;
}
```

I've tried a  bunch of  different stuff already. I didn't find similar cases also. But I hope it's something simple. Here are some things that I have tried already and didn't work:

- wrap `<nav>` and `<div class="carousel slide">` in one more layer of separated `<div>` tags
- change the `position` property in css
- put ids in both, to solve some sort of JavaScript problem with bootstrap.

If your answer is related to one of the above, fear not, it may be slightly different. Also, didn't use the snippet thing because bootstrap wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar z-index value should be higher than the carousel's one.

You also need to give properties to your affix classes :

> You must add CSS properties to handle the actual positions, with the exception of position:fixed on the .affix class.

Adding this in your CSS should fix your problems :

```
navbar.affix{
    /* values related to your affixed navbar position (for example, top: 0;) */
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Have a nice day.